# .NET Core WebAPI - 404 fallback with attribute routing

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core, webapi

While implementing my first restful webapi in **.NET Core 3.1** I am trying to implement a fallback routine for 404 Errors. My **Startup.cs** is actual looking like this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    // ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // ...
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToController("EndpointNotFound", "Fallback");
    });
}
```

In this configuration, the 404 fallback takes effect before the actual route to the respective controller. I am using the attribute routing in the api controllers. Is it generally possible to use the `MapFallbackToController()` method inside attribute routing? If not, is there an useful middleware alternative to it?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Some options are available  to implement this you can start from this and explore other possibilities (The following are configured in Configure method in Startup.cs):

Option 1 `app.UseStatusCodePages();` this will show the builtin default pages.

Option 2 `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("~/MyCustomController/{0}");` the placeholder `{0}` will populate with the HttpStatusCode eg: 404

> This method is commonly used when the app:
>
> - Should redirect the client to a different endpoint, usually in cases where > a different app processes the error. For web apps, the client's browser
>   address bar reflects the redirected endpoint.
> - Shouldn't preserve and return the original status code with the initial redirect response.

Option 3 `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("~/MyCustomController/{0}");` same with Option 2 with some difference

> This method is commonly used when the app should:
>
> - Process the request without redirecting to a different endpoint. For web
>   apps, the client's browser address bar reflects the originally requested >endpoint.
> - Preserve and return the original status code with the response.

You can use this as a reference for more broad detail in handling errors [Handle errors in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0)